# Angular Compatibility on different browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angularjs, web-services

i have designed a angularjs page to display records in table via webservices in intranet network and able to run this page on some machine's with same browser version

the page cannot display the data and show black where data is present but on the other end it display the records on other machine too..

Don't know how i got this  problem i am using this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
```

and after that i am able to work on some of the machine but not all with the same configuration and same browser version

(used pure HTML and ajax to call webservice in aspx page having a master)

Please help me to resolve it...

Comment: angular 1.2+ is not supporting old browsers (mainly ie8).. can you specify what you consider as different browsers (with versions numbers)?

Comment: hi, i am using angular 1 and run the file on different machine's having same IE 11 Version's but in some of the machine it cannot load the data and just blank the field without any error in console.